# What types of data can be extracted from a non-motion flight simulator?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-simulator

What are the types of data that can be extracted from a non-motion flight simulator?

Based on the type of data I want to do:

1. A comparison study between flight simulator data and ground-based systems data
2. To know if it's possible to calculate the fuel consumed by an aircraft while following certain ATC procedures, so that further improvements in fuel consumption can be explored by altering those procedures

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the representativeness of the modeling.

If your fuel system model, your engine model, and your aero model are representative of the aircraft, whatever is the qualification of the simulator, you will have good results. However, it will never be as accurate as the aircraft because of the unprecision of the modelisation and the fact that we are not able to modelise the thermodynamic part of the engine. We are using tables to get that and it creates a lot of inconsistency.

For example, if you try to look at the engine consumption in cruise it will be pretty accurate, but during acceleration phases, it will not be accurate at all due to the inconsistencies.

A simulator qualified as FNPT II + MCC under EASA or Level 5 under FAA should have the same representativeness as a Full Flight Simulator Level D for all the models talked above. So it will give you a good idea, but will never be accurate. However, it is still the best you can have from a simulation.

Comment: You could as well add that comparatively simulations will still give significant results even if the values are not 100% accurate.

Comment: That was my first and last point. You will have good results but not 100% accurate. The acceptability of it is not my responsibility.

Comment: maybe i was expecting to see it written separately, because the OP may miss it as I did. ;)

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't though about that.

Answer (score 0):

Both motion or no motion platforms - the basic simulation is nearly identical - except that (being a little more on the expensive side) motion simulators (or better said: the internal systems of the airplane) might be programmed.

1) nearly all simulators are ground based, so I do not understand what you want to say.

2) surely - just run the simulation (manned or via some automatic systems) with different parameters (in this case from ATC procedures) and collect the data...

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: ground based systems in the sense that I'll be comparing with the surveillance systems data and also using ATC modelling and simulation tool.